# PHP code highlighting in Org mode in Emacs not working

Tags: php, emacs, org-mode

I am using:

GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.8)

When I try to do in Org mode:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC php
<?php
echo "Hello";
?>
#+END_SRC
```

There is no highlighting. Everything  is gray.

If I change `#+BEGIN_SRC php` to `#+BEGIN_SRC js` or `#+BEGIN_SRC perl` it works but, of course, the coloring is wrong because it is not for php but for js or perl respectively.

So, why is it not working for the most prominent web scripting language in the world? Any way how can I make it work?

Comment: Have a look at [this question in Emacs SE](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/45790/17548)